# How to play shoutcast live stream in android using titanium studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, shoutcast

Hi im trying to play a shoutcast stream using this:

```
var urlStreaming1 = "http://shoutcasturl:8026";

streamer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
        url : urlStreaming[e.source.id],
        preload : true,
        allowBackground : true
    });
```

but i get no sound using latest titanium studio version plus android api 4.0

```
Application type: mobile Titanium SDK: Titanium SDK version: 2.1.2 (08/24/12 14:46 ed7f777)

Platform & version: Android 4.1 google api

Device: Android emulator

Host Operating System: OSX 10.8.2 mountain lion

Titanium Studio: Titanium Studio, build: 2.1.2.201208301612
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this Code embedded with your code this is working Fine.
Firstly you, create you AudioPlayer path then, you Can Play and Stop.

```
var sound = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({url:'http://202.6.74.107:8060/triplej.mp3'});

var stopSound = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Stop Sound',
    top:160,
    width:250,
    height:40
});
stopSound.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    sound.stop();
});

var startSound = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Play sound',
    top:110,
    width:250,
    height:40
});
startSound.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    Ti.API.info('playing sound with mode ' + modeArray[count].desc + ' count ' + count);
    sound.play();
});
```

Cheers.....!

Comment: thanks for ur answer , but i cant use that :( i have shoutcast aac stream not .mp3 so my url is justs like this:http://184.164.135.242:8026/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var streamer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({ url: 'http://shoutcasturl:8026;', });
streamer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put an app together with Titanium that streams an AAC shoutcast using the following:

**for iOS**

Use a videoPlayer and not audioPlayer:

```
var streamer = Ti.Media.createVideoPlayer({
            url : 'http://198.144.148.12:8000/'
        });
        streamer.play();
```

**for Android**

audioPlayer or videoPlayer do not support AAC at all so I developed the following module:

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5728